# Postgresql View aggregating data

Tags: sql, postgresql, view, query-optimization, materialized-views

I've got a problem to make this "nice" and efficient, as well as easy to read. Unfortunately it's lacking both properties.

Given a table with `date,transaction_type,username` and `credits`, I want to generate a view which summarizes into these fields: `date_from,date_next,username,credits_total,credits_total`

Explanation:

- date_from and date_to are this first of a month and the next first of a month. (e.g. 2022-06-01 and 2022-07-01)
- username is grouped and so only one same username per date_from/date_next pair
- credits_total is the sum of credit_change where transaction = 'charge'
- credits_left is credits_total - sum(credits_change where transaction_type = 'usage')

I've identified multiple problems and were partially able to fix them:

- date_from/_next is easy with `date_trunc('month', date)` and `date_trunc('month', date) + interval '1 month''
- group username/dates is possible with group by
- making credits_total without duplication is hard. Or is subquery the only solution?
- credits left is almost the same, but with other transaction_type and subtracting from credits_total. How Can I reuse the credits_total?

What I came up with (and am very unhappy with)

The source table:

```
create table usage  -- simplified
(
    datetime timestamp default now() not null,
    transaction_type varchar(16) not null,
    user varchar(128) not null,
    credits_change int not null,
);
```

My code for the view:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW token_usage
AS
SELECT 
       -- trivial:
       user,
       date_trunc('month', datetime) as date_from,
       date_trunc('month', datetime) + interval '1 month' as date_next,

       -- sum of credits_change with requirement + duplication
       (    -- see here. first time
            SELECT sum(credits_change)
            FROM usage
            WHERE transaction_type = 'charge'
            AND datetime BETWEEN date_trunc('month', datetime) AND date_trunc('month', datetime) + interval '1 month'
       ) as credits_total,

       -- sum of credits change minus other sum and more duplication
       (   -- see here. using the same again
           SELECT sum(credits_change)
           FROM usage
           WHERE transaction_type = 'charge'
           AND datetime BETWEEN date_trunc('month', datetime) AND date_trunc('month', datetime) + interval '1 month'
       ) - (  -- see here. using the same again, but with different transaction_type
           SELECT sum(credits_change)
           FROM usage
           WHERE transaction_type = 'usage'
           AND datetime BETWEEN date_trunc('month', datetime) AND date_trunc('month', datetime) + interval '1 month'
       ) as credits_left
    FROM usage
    GROUP BY user_name, datetime, datetime_next_start
WITH DATA;
```

Tbh it seems I'm just missing some postgresql tool, to make this better.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: _"am very unhappy with"_ - the unhappy part is mostly described in the code comments? Would it help to expand on those points directly in the SO Question text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing some sample data and expected output to try the query, the following can surely taken as a sketch for your complete solution. I guess, the main point here is knowing about the `FILTER` clause for aggregation functions(*):

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW token_usage AS

SELECT
    user,
    date_trunc('month', datetime) as date_from,
    date_trunc('month', datetime) + interval '1 month' as date_next,
    
    SUM(credits_change) FILTER (WHERE transaction_type = 'charge') as credits_total,
    SUM(credits_change) FILTER (WHERE transaction_type = 'charge')
        - SUM(credits_change) FILTER (WHERE transaction_type = 'usage') as credits_left
FROM usage
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
```

Alternative with less duplication but maybe less readable due to subquery:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW token_usage AS

SELECT 
    user,
    date_from,
    date_from + interval '1 month' as date_next,
    credits_total,
    credits_total - credits_usage as credits_left
FROM (
    SELECT
        user,
        date_trunc('month', datetime) as date_from,
    
        SUM(credits_change) FILTER (WHERE transaction_type = 'charge') as credits_total,
        SUM(credits_change) FILTER (WHERE transaction_type = 'usage') as credits_usage
    FROM usage
    GROUP BY 1, 2 
) s
```

*) You can use a `CASE` clause instead of the `FILTER` as well:

```
SUM(abc) FILTER (WHERE condition)

-- generally the same as

SUM(
    CASE WHEN condition THEN 
        abc 
    END
)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! FILTER was exactly what I needed and this even helps with the parts, which I left out to make my example simpler. <3 !

Comment: The last part is wrong. `SUM(abc) FILTER (WHERE condition)` can be converted to `SUM(CASE WHEN condition THEN abc END)`, not to `CASE WHEN condition THEN SUM(abc) END`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner of course, you're right!